# Join Linq Entity With Datatable

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework

I want to join Data Table with a linq entity. Here is the code hope fully u will understand what i am trying to do here with the code

```
var db = new TempR_ClientRCEntities();
DataTable dbc = GetAllSites();
List<object> temp = dbc.AsEnumerable().ToList<object>();

var thermoTypes = from type in db.TempR_ThermometerType
                  join site in dbc on type.SiteID equals dbc.SiteId
                  select type;
```

Comment: And what's the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use join, but that will require loading all thermometer types to client (assume site id has integer type):

```
var query = from t in db.TempR_ThermometerType.AsEnumerable()
            join r in dbc.AsEnumerable()
                 on t.SiteID equals r.Field<int>("SiteId") 
            select t;
```

Or you can use server-side filtering of thermometer types, but in that case you need to pass site ids to server - it will generate SQL operator IN):

```
var ids = dbc.AsEnumerable().Select(r => r.Field<int>("SiteId")).Distinct();
var query = from t in db.TempR_ThermometerType
            where ids.Contains(t.SiteID)
            select t;
```

Comment: Now im having problem casting them

Comment: var thermoTypes = from type in db.TempR_ThermometerType
                          join r in dbc.AsEnumerable() on type.SiteID equals r.Field<int>("Comp_CompanyId")
                          select new { type , SiteName = r.Field<string>("Comp_Name")};

Comment: @xainu31 what is type of site id both in database and datatable?

Comment: @xainu31 your code does not looks like code from your question. And it cannot work, because you are trying to compare anonymous type having two properties with integer. Is `42` equals `{ type, "Microsoft" }`?